serving json, geojson from static domain causes CORS issues in nginx
i built a nginx on the cloud, where /static/images and /static/data folder are served as the static folder.
the basic configuration is made as followed below
server{
    location /static/ {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range;' always;
                 if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
                    return 204;
                }
    
                access_log off;
                expires max;
                alias /opt/static/;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           }
}

it is ok to access to the images and json files from the browsers but from a localhost based react app failed to access these files due to CORS issues.
this is the debug info from the chrome

but I had already added the access-control-allow-orgin header in nginx config.
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;

so right now still get stuck, don't know how to deal with it

Your location doesn't match anything. You've missed ~ prefix.

thanks for reminding this, sorry for the typing error. i re-editted the content, but still the main issue is the CORS

Are you sure the request is ended up in this location? Show full config of server block.
